# didConnectPeripheral delegate is not being called on iOS 13

Tags: ios, bluetooth, mapping, ibeacon

`didConnectPeripheral` delegate is not being called on iOS 13 version. It is working fine below iOS 13. Does anything need to be added in iOS 13 to get connect with the device?

`centralManagerDidUpdateState` is updating but connect is not calling. I don't know why.

I tried adding "Alway bluetooth required" in Info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with iOS 13, the system will automatically prompt the user to grant an app permission to use bluetooth when the app tries to scan for or connect to a bluetooth device.  The message in the generic dialog may be augmented with a custom message by the following entry in Info.plist:

```
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app uses bluetooth to perform XYZ functions.</string>
```

If the user denies permission when presented this dialog, the app will not be able to scan for or connect to bluetooth devices.  It is possible that your app presented this dialog and you did not notice and accidentally denied permission.

To check this, you can go to Settings > Privacy > Bluetooth and check if your app is granted bluetooth permission.

Comment: Its already added but not use, I think I need to add "registerForConnectionEvents" after state update?